# MySqlException: Field 'id' doesn't have a default value - Entity Framework Core 2.1

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc, pomelo-entityframeworkcore-mysql

I'm new to ASP.NET Core MVC. I'm getting error on inserting data to MySQL with entity framework Core.
While debugging i got id in minus(-2147482645) assigned by context.Why id is assigned by EF? How to resolve this error? Table in MySQL id column is NOTNULL, PK and Auto Increment set default.
[image]

**Here is my DBContextFile**

```
    {
        public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        { }

        public DbSet<PCBDesign> pCBDesigns { get; set; }



        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
    }
```

**Here is My Class**

```
    {

        [Key]
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string userId { get; set; }
        public string desginNo { get; set; }
        public DateTime Crdate { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string contact { get; set; }
        public string notes { get; set; }
    }
```

**After call** context.SaveChanges();
**Getting Error:**

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. ---> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Field 'id' doesn't have a default value ---> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Field 'id' doesn't have a default value
```

**Query of table creation:**

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `pcbdesigns`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!50503 SET character_set_client = utf8mb4 */;
CREATE TABLE `pcbdesigns` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `userId` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci,
  `desginNo` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci,
  `Crdate` datetime NOT NULL,
  `name` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci,
  `contact` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci,
  `notes` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Dumping data for table `pcbdesigns`
--

LOCK TABLES `pcbdesigns` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `pcbdesigns` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `pcbdesigns` VALUES ();
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `pcbdesigns` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;`
```

Comment: Does it work when you define/specify the model in `OnModelCreating`?

Comment: Is this the case when you modify an existing row in database table?

Comment: @Marko Radivojevic - This is happen when i add new data to context object.

Comment: @Progman When i assign value to model, id = 0, by default. id value got assigned on first line of `context.pCBDesigns.AddAsync(pCBDesign);` before this line id = 0; I also tried  `context.pCBDesigns.Add(pCBDesign);` facing same issue.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem is solved! 
Step 1:** Copied table creation script for each table
**Step 2:** Dropped table created from same script.
**Step 3:** Added one dummy row in table.

Additional info: I did migration from code first approach i think there was some problem with Entity Framework Core while Migration. From now I will not do migration it will lead more error for me.

Thanks.

Comment: Migrations should work without issues. How does the `INSERT` query look like, that is being logged by EF Core? How does the `PCBDesign` table look like (`CREATE TABLE` script)?

Comment: @lauxjpn i'm updating in Question.

Comment: Please still add the `INSERT` query, [logged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/logging?tabs=v3) by EF Core.